# How do I retrieve contacts google-api-php-client

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I have been looking through all of the examples for the google-api-php-client but haven't been able to find anything which relates to getting contacts with this API.

I can successfully authenticate and get an access token which allows me to "manage contacts" but haven't been able to use that access token to get contacts. I'm using the one on Github rather than the one on Google code because I want to use it with composer but they do seem to differ slightly?

I've looked in the following places

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples

and the services https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/src/Google/Service

but there doesn't appear to be any services which use the scopes which the api documentation states to use.

I've also looked at various other tutorials but they seem to relate to the old API or aren't even close to working. Class names are wrong and passing around incorrect information etc

This may not be the right place to ask but I'm struggling to find any useful documentation or working tutorials which relate to this.

Cheers